# How to pass Drop down menu value to another func or widget? Flutter/Dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have drop down menu with 2 arguments, title and id. drop down selected item will show just title arguments but i want to pass title's id to the another widget like future builder, so any idea?

```
DropdownButton<String>(
                value: dropdownValue,
                //icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward,),
                iconSize: 22,
                elevation: 16,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                underline: Container(
                  height: 2,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                isDense: true,
                hint: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 20),
                  child: Text(
                    'انتخاب موقعیت',
                    style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "IranSans"),
                  ),
                ),
                onChanged: (String newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    dropdownValue = newValue;
                  });
                },
                items: sos.map((lst lst1) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: lst1.title,
                    child: Text(lst1.title),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),

class lst{
  String title;
  int id;

  lst({this.id, this.title});
}

List<lst> sos = <lst>[
  lst(id: 2, title: 'شهرک سعدی'),
  lst(id: 3, title: 'وکیل - طفریه - مردوخ'),
  lst(id: 4, title: 'شهرک ۵ آذر'),
  lst(id: 5, title: 'بلوار شبلی'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example that you provided I see that you are creating the dropdown using the string but rather you should create it using the list object that you mentioned in the example.
I have created a sample example for you check it out and let me know if it works

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  

  String countryValue;
  List<String> countriesList = [];
  List<String> cityList = [];
  String cityValue;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  List<lst> sos = <lst>[
    lst(id: 2, title: 'شهرک سعدی'),
    lst(id: 3, title: 'وکیل - طفریه - مردوخ'),
    lst(id: 4, title: 'شهرک ۵ آذر'),
    lst(id: 5, title: 'بلوار شبلی'),
  ];

  lst dropdownValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Users List "),
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: 300,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              DropdownButton<lst>(
                value: dropdownValue,
                //icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward,),
                iconSize: 22,
                elevation: 16,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                underline: Container(
                  height: 2,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                isDense: true,
                hint: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 20),
                  child: Text(
                    'انتخاب موقعیت',
                    style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "IranSans"),
                  ),
                ),
                onChanged: (lst newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    dropdownValue = newValue;
                  });
                  print(dropdownValue.id);
                  print(dropdownValue.title);
                },
                items: sos.map((lst lst1) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<lst>(
                    value: lst1,
                    child: Text(lst1.title),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    
  }
}

class lst {
  String title;
  int id;

  lst({this.id, this.title});
}
```

Now when you select the drop down  you will get the id as well as the title and you can pass it to the another widget.
Let me know if it works